# how do i passing nesting object as a props in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to use the open weather api to show the weather . the api response with an object. i have a state

```
state = {
        cityWeather: {},

    }
```

and on api response i am setting that response to the cityWeather; this is done in  weather main components

```
const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&ApiKey=2747592557924542516e283a7f905a81`;
        axios.get(url).then((response) => {
            const weatherData=response.data;

this.setState(()=>({ cityWeather:weatherData}));
```

the response i am getting is

```
{coord: {…}, weather: Array(1), base: "stations", main: {…}, wind: {…}, …}
base:"stations"
clouds :{all: 48}
cod:200
coord: {lon: 10.74, lat: 59.91}
dt:1536870000
id:3143244
main: {temp: 13, pressure: 1010, humidity: 66, temp_min: 13, temp_max: 13}
name:"Oslo"
sys:
{type: 1, id: 5325, message: 0.0038, country: "NO", sunrise: 1536813716, …}
weather : [{…}]
wind : {speed: 5.7, deg: 220}}
```

now from parent component i want to pass this cityWeather data as a props to its child component CurrentWeathe as

```
<CurrentWeather  data={this.state.cityWeather}/>
```

now when i accessing the props in the child component , react is throwing this error

```
{this.props.data.name} //this line works 
{this.props.data.wind.speed} //this give me error saying Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'speed' of undefined. because wind is object inside the main object.
```

my question is how do i pass these nested object as props.

if i set all the value individually instead of object, this works , but then how do i pass these individual value as prop at once.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because if your api is taking some time to respond(which is normal) then component will render without values first and after getting values it will render again (if this.setState() or this.forceUpdate() is called). 
 So at the first render Child will render without values so it will through error like this to overcome this problem we can give different return values

1. if not have data
2. after getting data

change to this in the render method of CurrentWeather

```
render(){
 if(!this.props.data.name){
  return(
    <div>
       Loading....
    </div>
 )
 }else {
  return (
  .....//Your current return code for CurrentWeather  class (component)
  .....
  )

 }
}
```

Comment: if you look at the response if i use {this.props.data.name} will work. so its not the issue of loading . the error only comes when i am accessing values from nested object like  {this.props.data.sys.country} or {this.props.data.wind.speed}

Comment: `this.props.data.name` is undefined which is okay with no error. But `this.props.data.wind.speed` will give you error because `this.props.data.wind` is undefined that is okay but `this.props.data.wind.speed`  is **undefined.wind** which is error. Also we can see in error statement c**an not read property wind of undefined**

Comment: `this.props.data.name` is undefined(you can console.log() this ) which is not an error but **undefined.something** is error

Answer (score 1):

ok i found the solution,
my state:

```
state = {
             cityWeather:null  ,

    }
```

rather then doing `this.setState(()=>({ cityWeather:weatherData}));` directly, i created a new data object and extracted all the values and set it to thisobject

```
const data={
            cloudiness:weatherData.weather[0].description,
               lat:weatherData.coord.lat,
               lon:weatherData.coord.lon,
               icon:weatherData.weather[0].icon,
               sunrise:new Date(weatherData.sys.sunrise * 1000).toLocaleTimeString(),
               sunset:new Date(weatherData.sys.sunset * 1000).toLocaleTimeString(),
               humidity:weatherData.main.humidity,
               currentTemp:weatherData.main.temp,
               pressure:weatherData.main.pressure,
               wind:weatherData.wind.speed,
               cityName:`${weatherData.name},${weatherData.sys.country}`,
               date:moment().format("DD MMM YYYY") 
            }
            this.setState(()=>({cityWeather:data}));
```

and i the props are passes like this

```
let  currentweather;
        if (this.state.cityWeather != null) {
            currentweather=<CurrentWeather  {...this.state.cityWeather} />
        }
```

and in child component the value are extracted like this:

```
const { lat,lon ,wind, currentTemp, cityName,
       cloudiness,pressure,humidity,sunrise,sunset,icon,date}=this.props;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error is `Cannot read property 'speed' of undefined` that means `wind` is undefined. If you `console.log(this.props.data)` you should be able to see all the available properties in chrome devtools.

It shouldn't matter how deeply nested your objects are in your child component. One way to make accessing the data easier, though, is spreading your state into the child components: `<CurrentWeather {...this.state.cityWeather} />`

Then you can access data with `this.props.name`.

There may be other issues with the way you're accessing props, but it'll be hard to tell as the response you posted is incomplete.

Comment: if i only use {this.props.data } in child componenet i get this errorUncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.